# Can Intel 82865G do widescreen?

Tags: windows-xp, integrated-graphics

I connected a Samsung SyncMaster P2270 (widescreen) to a Dell Dimension 3000 that uses the integrated Intel 82865G for graphics. The problem is that there are no widescreen resolutions to choose from. The latest Intel driver is used (14.17) and it is set to use 94MB. This seems to be quite a common problem but even though there are a lot of google hits I can't find a satisfying answer.

It's connected with a DVI-A- to D-Sub (VGA) cable and no EDID is found.

Is there a way to make Intel 82865G show widescreen resolutions?

PS. It seems people are having greater success in Linux so it seems that this is indeed a software problem. DS.

Comment: Settled for the 1280x768 for the time being. It's not using the Samsung SyncMaster P2270 to it's full potential but it's at least a widescreen mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can Intel 82865G do widescreen?

In a word, yes.

Intel® 82865G Graphics Controller
Supported Video Modes

Intel® 865G Chipset Supported Windows Configuration Modes

2D + O = 2D display + full screen overlay
2D = 2D display only

Screen
Resolution Color
Depth (bpp)
Refresh
Rate (Hz) Mode
Type

```
640 x 480 8, 16, 32 60, 72, 75, 85, 100, 120 2D + O
800 x 600 8, 16, 32 60, 72, 75, 85, 100, 120 2D + O
1024 x 768 8, 16, 32 60, 70, 75, 85, 100, 120 2D + O
1152 x 864 8, 16, 32 60, 75, 85, 100 2D + O
1280 x 720 8, 16, 32 60, 75, 85, 100 2D + O
1280 x 768 8, 16, 32 60, 75, 85 2D + O
1280 x 960 8, 16, 32 60, 75, 85 2D + O
1280 x 1024 8, 16, 32 60, 75, 85, 100 2D + O
1280 x 1024 8, 16, 32 120 2D
1400 x 1050 8, 16, 32 60, 75, 85 2D + O
1600 x 900 8, 16, 32 60, 75, 85, 100 2D + O
1600 x 900 8, 16, 32 120 2D
1600 x 1200 8, 16, 32 60, 75, 85 2D + O
1600 x 1200 8, 16 100 2D
1856 x 1392 8, 16, 32 60 2D + O
1856 x 1392 8, 16 75 2D
1920 x 1080 8, 16, 32 60, 75 2D + O
1920 x 1080 8, 16 85, 100 2D
1920 x 1200 8, 16, 32 60 2D + O
1920 x 1200 8, 16 75 2D
1920 x 1440 8, 16 60, 75, 85 2D
1920 x 1440 32 60 2D
2048 x 1536 8, 16 60, 75 2D
2048 x 1536 32 60 2D
```

Can your Dell Dimension 3000 do widescreen?

Now that's a different question altogether, the modes may be limited within the Video BIOS Table (VBT) by Dell. You might be able to override these limitations with **[EnTech's PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)**.

*PowerStrip is shareware, try before you buy.*

Comment: I haven't tried PowerStrip yet but others have http://www.avsforum.com/avs-vb/showthread.php?t=1114978 and EntechTaiwan says it probably will not work http://forums.entechtaiwan.com/index.php?topic=18.0

Comment: always worth trying, it works fine for me with an Intel GMA 915 which is of course newer than the 865.

Comment: PowerStrip does not seem to be able to tweak the settings for Intel 82865G. And if I add custom resolutions they don't show up after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible.

Simply click the `Advanced` Button and then under the tab called `Adapters` click on `List All Modes`.

[image]

If you do not see it there, the next place to look is under the `Monitor` tab, make sure that the option `Hide modes that this monitor cannot display` is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did uncheck the "Hide modes" but there were  still no widescreen in the list.